# How to change for loop variables in python/django while for loop is running

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, for-loop

I want to change variables that define a for loop while the loop is running. It will make more sense when you see the code, so here it is:

```
days = form.instance.days

for i in range(0, days + 1):
    days_added = i
    current_end = class_start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=days_added)
    current_end_day = calendar.day_name[datetime.datetime.strptime(str(current_end), '%Y-%m-%d').weekday()]
    if current_end_day == 'Saturday' or current_end_day == 'Sunday':
        days = days + 1
```

You see, when I run the code `days = days + 1`, I want the `days` for `for i in range(0, days + 1):` to be updated, so that the number of total loops of the forloop will be increased by 1 whenever `days = days + 1` occurs. `days = form.instance.days` is increased by 1, but `days` in `for i in range(0, days + 1):` is not updated. I hope you guys could help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't, the range is evaluated once and for all before the loop runs. Use a `while` loop.

Comment: You can't. The loop it self is evaluated only once. Maybe you need a `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
for i in <expr>:
```

the expression  only gets evaluated once, so you cannot achieve what you want with a `for`loop. You can use a `while`instead:

```
i = 0
while i < days + 1:
    days_added = i
    current_end = class_start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=days_added)
    current_end_day = calendar.day_name[datetime.datetime.strptime(str(current_end), '%Y-%m-%d').weekday()]
    if current_end_day == 'Saturday' or current_end_day == 'Sunday':
        days = days + 1
    i += 1
```

Now the `i < days + 1` condition gets evaluated each time, and it will use the updated value of `days`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop may be better suited for your use case. You need to establish a condition for it to stop looping while avoiding falling on an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help!